# Camel, how to create genuine sync on direct endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

Camel (3.11 -  3.12.0-SNAPSHOT) Java 16.

In this example two messages are sent by timer. The second message started processing when the first is not finished yet. I expect messages are processed one by one in one DIRECT route.

```
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:cTimer?period=1&repeatCount=2")
                .process(e -> {
                    final Integer oldBody = timerMessageId.getAndIncrement();
                    log.info("Send message: {}", oldBody);
                    e.getIn().setHeader(KEY, oldBody);
                    final List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    e.getIn().setBody(list);
                })
                .to("direct:direct-order-file-process-route:" + psId);

        from(direct("direct-order-file-process-route:" + psId))
                .routeId("routeId:" + psId)
                .process(exchange -> {
                    log.info("Started process message: {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader(KEY));
                })
                .split()
                .body()
                .aggregate(header(KEY), this::aggregatorExchanges)
                .completionSize(5)
                .completionTimeout(1000L)
                .process(exchange -> {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    log.info("DONE: {} / {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader(KEY), exchange.getIn().getBody());
                })
                .end();
    }

    private Exchange aggregatorExchanges(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        List<Integer> drinks;
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            drinks = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            drinks = (List<Integer>) oldExchange.getIn().getBody();
        }
        drinks.add((Integer) newExchange.getIn().getBody());
        newExchange.getIn().setBody(drinks);
        return newExchange;
    }
```

Logs:

```
Send message: 1
Started process message: 1
Send message: 2
Started process message: 2
DONE: 1 / [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
DONE: 2 / [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
DONE: 1 / [6, 7, 8, 9]
DONE: 2 / [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Expected logs:

```
Send message: 1
Started process message: 1
DONE: 1 / [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
DONE: 1 / [6, 7, 8, 9]

Send message: 2
Started process message: 2
DONE: 2 / [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
DONE: 2 / [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The problem here is around of "aggregate" . Without aggregate "direct" works correctly.
Another words: direct and aggregate is not synchronized (they run in different threads). Direct is not waiting for aggregation completion.

Comment: May be add "synchronous=true" to your timer endpoint, so that the timer will have to wait for the completion of the first run before firing for the 2nd time ?

Comment: I tried this ("?synchronous=true") or even (direct("direct-order-file-process-route").advanced().synchronous(true)) but in vain.  But if add in aggregation strategy method (newExchange.setProperty(Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_ALL_GROUPS, true);)  all groups completed but order processing of "direct" endpoint still incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not at all a problem of synchronous processing or not. **Your expectation is simply a split message, not an aggregation**.

- You send **2 messages with different keys**, each containing a list of 9 numbers
- Both messages are **split to 9 individual messages**
- You expect the origin messages to be processed one after the other but this is against the concept of the aggregator

From the **aggregators perspective, 18 individual messages arrive**. 9 with key 1 and 9 with key 2. It doesn't know anything about the 2 origin messages, but aggregates these 18 messages by key.

Your log shows that process nicely.

1. First **message with key 1** is sent. It contains a list of 9 numbers.
2. The message is **split to 9 individual messages** each with one number.
3. The nine messages, all with the same key 1, arrive at the aggregator
4. Because the aggregator creates **aggregations of 5 messages (`completionSize(5)`)**, the **first aggregation completes** quickly and is produced (`DONE: 1 / [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`)
5. The **remaining 4 messages with key 1 are hold**, because 1 more message is needed to complete the aggreation
6. Meanwhile message with key 2, also containing 9 numbers is also split and 9 messages with key 2 arrive at the aggregator
7. It **starts a new aggregation** because the KEY is used as differentiator
8. So the **second aggregation completes quickly** and is produced (`DONE: 2 / [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`)
9. Again, for message 2, the **remaining 4 messages are hold**, because 1 more message is needed to complete the aggreation
10. At this moment **2 aggregations (key 1 and key 2) are holding 4 messages each** and are waiting for more messages.
11. Because no more messages arrive, the **`completionTimeout` kicks in** after 1 second without new messages
12. So the **2 "incomplete" aggregations are nevertheless closed** and produced (`DONE: 1 / [6, 7, 8, 9]` and `DONE: 2 / [6, 7, 8, 9]`)

If you want to get your "expected log", you **don't need an aggregator at all** because this is just a "custom messages splitting" that creates chunks of 5 numbers per message. You could for example [implement the Camel Split EIP in a bean](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html#_using_a_pojo_to_do_the_splitting) to implement this.